# Passig data with intent from activity to recyclerview in mainactivity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am recently creating simple application with recycler view. I hava MainActivity which contains recyclerview, UploadActivity which I edit texts and pass to recyclerview, and Adapter class. All I want to do is, I would like to create a new review in UploadActivity, and then pass the data to recyclerview in MainActivity.
I have been looking for the solution for a while to solve my problem.

Simply :

edit texts in uploadActivity -> pass data to added recyclerview in MainActivity.

I have 4 EditTextViews in upload activity, and I am confused how should I deal with the keys.

Here is the Adapter Code.

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
@NonNull

private ArrayList<MainData> list;

String key;

public MainAdapter(ArrayList<MainData> list, String key) {
    this.list = list;
    this.key = key;
}


@Override
public MainAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
   
    holder.tv_title.setText(list.get(position).getTv_title());
    holder.tv_author.setText(list.get(position).getTv_author());
    holder.tv_start.setText(list.get(position).getTv_start());
    holder.tv_end.setText(list.get(position).getTv_end());

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (list != null ? list.size() : 0);
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tv_title;
    protected TextView tv_author;
    protected TextView tv_start;
    protected TextView tv_end;

    public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.tv_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.tv_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        this.tv_start = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_start);
        this.tv_end = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_end);

    }

}
```

MainData :

```
public class MainData {

String tv_title;
String tv_author;
String tv_start;
String tv_end;

public MainData(String tv_title,String tv_author, String tv_start, String tv_end) {

    this.tv_title = tv_title;
    this.tv_author = tv_author;
    this.tv_start = tv_start;
    this.tv_end = tv_end;

}

public String getTv_author() {
    return tv_author;
}

public void setTv_author(String tv_author) {
    this.tv_author = tv_author;
}

public String getTv_title() {
    return tv_title;
}

public void setTv_title(String tv_title) {
    this.tv_title = tv_title;
}

public String getTv_end() {
    return tv_end;
}

public void setTv_end(String tv_end) {
    this.tv_end = tv_end;
}

public String getTv_start() {
    return tv_start;
}

public void setTv_start(String tv_start) {
    this.tv_start = tv_start;
}
}
```

MainActivity which is going to receive data and set recyclerview (and where I am stuck):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<MainData> list;
private MainAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager manager;

String pass_title;
String pass_author;
String pass_start;
String pass_end;

String key = "key";





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // START OF ONCREATE
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new MainAdapter(list,key);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Upload Activity : where I am stuck as well.

```
private ArrayList<MainData> list;
private MainAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager manager;

       Button uploading = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload_upload);
       uploading.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // UPLOAD BUTTON
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            EditText input_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.upload_title);
            String temp1 = input_title.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("key",temp1); 

            EditText input_author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.upload_author);
            String temp2 = input_author.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("temp2",temp2);

            start = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_date);
            String s = start.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("start",s);

            end = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.end_date);
            String e = end.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("end",e);

            MainData mainData = new MainData(pass_title, pass_author, pass_start, pass_end);
            list.add(mainData);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


           startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
    }); // UPLOAD BUTTON
```

I am sorry for this long question. I am new at coding, so any kind of strong feedback will be welcomed! Thank you in advance.

Comment: `intent.putExtra("key",temp1)` You are not showing what intent would be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question proprely. So basically you want to put the 4 String values in UploadActivity inside the recyclerview of MainActivity .

To do that pass those 4 values via intent.putExtra . (et1 , et2 , et3 ..)

Get it inside the 2nd activity and save it in an arraylist.

```
Arraylist<String> arraylist = new ArrayList();
arraylist.add("value from edit text 1")
arraylist.add("value from edit text 2")
.
.
.
```

Then pass this arraylist to your recyclerview to populate it

Comment: `"value from edit text 1"` You mean from that intent that was received. Im pretty sure i do not understand your answer. What did you solve?